# Equivalent of *nix fold in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Today I had a few hundred items (IDs from SQL query) and needed to paste them into another query to be readable by an analyst.  I needed *nix `fold` command.  I wanted to take the 300 lines and reformat them as multiple numbers per line seperated by a space.  I would have used `fold -w 100 -s`.

Similar tools on *nix include `fmt` and `par`.

On Windows is there an easy way to do this in PowerShell?  I expected one of the `*-Format` commandlets to do it, but I couldn't find it.  I'm using PowerShell v4.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25173/how-can-i-wrap-text-at-a-certain-column-size

```
# Input Data
# simulate a set of 300 numeric IDs from 100,000 to 150,000
100001..100330 | 
    Out-File _sql.txt -Encoding ascii

# I want output like:
# 100001,  100002,  100003,  100004,  100005, ... 100010, 100011
# 100012,  100013,  100014,  100015,  100016, ... 100021, 100021
# each line less than 100 characters.
```

Comment: I tried `-join ' '` and the output does wrap at 100 characters, but it wraps in the middle of the number.  I want to wrap at spaces so the value of the numbers aren't changed by the wrapping.

Comment: Just found http://vgoenka.tripod.com/unixscripts/fold.awk.txt which might work in conjunction with gawk.exe that ships with GIT cli on Windows.

Comment: See also: [doing textwrap and dedent in Windows PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417663/doing-textwrap-and-dedent-in-windows-powershell-or-dotnet-aka-net)

Comment: @EmperorXLII thanks for the link. For future readers: the solutions at Emporer's link use `for` and native types, so are probably MUCH faster on data sets 10,000-10,000,000 items. Loops are known to be 10x faster than pipelines (when the data set fits in RAM).

Answer (score 7):

Depending on how big the file is you could read it all into memory, join it with spaces and then split on 100* characters or the next space

```powershell
(Get-Content C:\Temp\test.txt) -join " " -split '(.{100,}?[ |$])' | Where-Object{$_}
```

That regex looks for 100 characters then the first space after that. That match is then `-split` but since the pattern is wrapped in parenthesis the match is returned instead of discarded. The `Where` removes the empty entries that are created in between the matches.

**Small sample to prove theory**

```powershell
@"
134
124
1
225
234
4
34
2
42
342
5
5
2
6
"@.split("`n") -join " "  -split '(.{10,}?[ |$])' | Where-Object{$_}
```

The above splits on 10 characters where possible. If it cannot the numbers are still preserved. Sample is based on me banging on the keyboard with my head.

```powershell
134 124 1 
225 234 4 
34 2 42 
342 5 5 
2 6
```

You could then make this into a function to get the simplicity back that you are most likely looking for. It can get better but this isn't really the focus of the answer.

```powershell
Function Get-Folded{
    Param(
        [string[]]$Strings,
        [int]$Wrap = 50
    )
    $strings  -join " " -split "(.{$wrap,}?[ |$])" | Where-Object{$_}
}
```

**Again with the samples**

```powershell
PS C:\Users\mcameron> Get-Folded -Strings (Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt) -wrap 40
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
... output truncated...
```

You can see that it was supposed to split on 40 characters but the second line is longer. It split on the next space after 40 to preserve the word.

Comment: This seems to have problems with Unicode characters. This `…` becomes `â€¦`.  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Can you link me to a larger sample to test with and let me know your PowerShell version?

Comment: I'm running version 5.1.  Another example is `é` becomes `Ã©` and `—` becomes `â€”`.

Comment: I found the solution.  I changed it to `Get-Content C:\Temp\test.txt -Encoding UTF8` and that fixed it.

Comment: Oh. I was about to say that I don't see a problem. but if you were using that sample from my code then yes you would get that problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's one item per line, and you want to join every 100 items onto a single line separated by a space you could put all the output into a text file then do this:

```
gc c:\count.txt -readcount 100 | % {$_ -join " "}
```

Comment: ah i missed the part about characters...mine just joins every 100 items. the other answers are probably more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

When I saw this, the first thing that came to my mind was abusing Format-Table to do this, mostly because it knows how to break the lines properly when you specify a width. After coming up with a function, it seems that the other solutions presented are shorter and probably easier to understand, but I figured I'd still go ahead and post this solution anyway:

```
function fold {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObject,
        [Alias('w')]
        [int] $LineWidth = 100,
        [int] $ElementWidth
    )

    begin {
        $SB = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

        if ($ElementWidth) {
            $SBFormatter = "{0,$ElementWidth} "
        }
        else {
            $SBFormatter = "{0} "
        }
    }

    process {
        foreach ($CurrentObject in $InputObject) {
            [void] $SB.AppendFormat($SBFormatter, $CurrentObject)
        }
    }

    end {
        # Format-Table wanted some sort of an object assigned to it, so I 
        # picked the first static object that popped in my head:
        ([guid]::Empty | Format-Table -Property @{N="DoesntMatter"; E={$SB.ToString()}; Width = $LineWidth } -Wrap -HideTableHeaders |
            Out-String).Trim("`r`n")
    }
}
```

Using it gives output like this:

```
PS C:\> 0..99 | Get-Random -Count 100 | fold
1 73 81 47 54 41 17 87 2 55 30 91 19 50 64 70 51 29 49 46 39 20 85 69 74 43 68 82 76 22 12 35 59 92 
13 3 88 6 72 67 96 31 11 26 80 58 16 60 89 62 27 36 37 18 97 90 40 65 42 15 33 24 23 99 0 32 83 14  
21 8 94 48 10 4 84 78 52 28 63 7 34 86 75 71 53 5 45 66 44 57 77 56 38 79 25 93 9 61 98 95          

PS C:\> 0..99 | Get-Random -Count 100 | fold -ElementWidth 2
74 89 10 42 46 99 21 80 81 82  4 60 33 45 25 57 49  9 86 84 83 44  3 77 34 40 75 50  2 18  6 66 13  
64 78 51 27 71 97 48 58  0 65 36 47 19 31 79 55 56 59 15 53 69 85 26 20 73 52 68 35 93 17  5 54 95  
23 92 90 96 24 22 37 91 87  7 38 39 11 41 14 62 12 32 94 29 67 98 76 70 28 30 16  1 61 88 43  8 63  
72                                                                                                  

PS C:\> 0..99 | Get-Random -Count 100 | fold -ElementWidth 2 -w 40
21 78 64 18 42 15 40 99 29 61  4 95 66  
86  0 69 55 30 67 73  5 44 74 20 68 16  
82 58  3 46 24 54 75 14 11 71 17 22 94  
45 53 28 63  8 90 80 51 52 84 93  6 76  
79 70 31 96 60 27 26  7 19 97  1 59  2  
65 43 81  9 48 56 25 62 13 85 47 98 33  
34 12 50 49 38 57 39 37 35 77 89 88 83  
72 92 10 32 23 91 87 36 41
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using.

```
# simulate a set of 300 SQL IDs from 100,000 to 150,000
100001..100330 | 
    %{ "$_, " } | # I'll need this decoration in the SQL script
    Out-File _sql.txt -Encoding ascii

gc .\_sql.txt -ReadCount 10 | %{ $_ -join ' ' }
```

Thanks everyone for the effort and the answers.  I'm really surprised there wasn't a way to do this with `Format-Table` without the use of `[guid]::Empty` in Rohn Edward's answer.

My IDs are much more consistent than the example I gave, so Noah's use of `gc -ReadCount` is by far the simplest solution in this particular data set, but in the future I'd probably use Matt's answer or the answers linked to by Emperor in comments.

Comment: Format-Wide works when you have an object.  You can use `Select-String` (our grep) to read every line as a Match object.  `sls .* .\_sql.txt | Format-Wide Line -Column 10`.  This produces: `100001,        100002,        100003,       100004,       100005,       100006,       100007,       100008,       100009,       100010, `.  Same caveats as original answer: only works when items are all nearly the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
$array = 
(@'
1
2
3
10
11
100
101
'@).split("`n") |
foreach {$_.trim()}

$array = $array * 40

$SB = New-Object Text.StringBuilder(100,100)

foreach ($item in $array) {

Try { [void]$SB.Append("$item ") }

Catch {
         $SB.ToString()
         [void]$SB.Clear()
         [Void]$SB.Append("$item ")
      }
}    
#don't forget the last line
$SB.ToString()

1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 
1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 
1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 
1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 
1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 
1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 
1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101 1 2 3 10 11 100 101
```

Maybe not as compact as you were hoping for, and there may be better ways to do it, but it seems to work.